# jQuery callback after slideUp

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.SomeDiv').slideUp(400);
setTimeout(function () { SomeFunction(); }, 400);
```

How do I rewrite this and remove the `setTimeout` so that `SomeFunction` becomes a call-back function of `slideUp`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Method [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) has `callback` argument. So you can do it easily with:

```
$(".SomeDiv").slideUp(400, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    SomeFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In fact you can just simply use:

```js
$(".SomeDiv").slideUp(400, CallBackFunction);
```